# i want to return type int this.Time object how would i go about doing this

Tags: java

first of all some ground work heres the constructor im using

```
// user inputs a value say 4000 seconds, and then constructor will then convert that into hours, minutes and seconds
public Time(int inTttlSecs)
    {
        // compute the hours, minutes, seconds
        // from the total seconds.
        this.Hours = inTttlSecs/ 3600;
        this.Minutes = (inTttlSecs - (this.Hours * 3600)) / 60;
        this.Seconds = (inTttlSecs - (this.Hours * 3600) - 
            (this.Minutes * 60));

    }
```

this constructor along with appropriate get and set methods for those 3 instance variables is used to create a time object

now the problem is i want to create a Time object
using this method and return type int this time object in total seconds

```
@return int this Time object in seconds

public int getTotalSecs()
    {        
    // here i want to return type int this Time object total seconds
         return 0;
    }
```

question is i can create a Time object

```
Time totalSecs
```

but i dont know how to make it type int or return the total seconds
any ideas?
or if you cant answer, point me in the right direction or clue me in as i am lost

// responding to the answer below i am using class time as a instance variable object in another class so i need to return it as a new object

Comment: If that's a method inside your `Time` class, then it has access to the `Hours`, `Minutes` and `Seconds` fields.  It seems to me you could probably do some arithmetic with those, to get the right number to return.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just store the total seconds given in the constructor in a global variable and return that?

```
private int totalSeconds;

public Time(inTttlSecs) {
    this.totalSeconds = inTttlSecs;
    ...
}

public int getTotalSeconds() {
    return totalSeconds;
}
```

But if you can't do that, here's a formula that will return the total seconds:

```
public int getTotalSeconds() {
    return 3600 * hours + 60 * minutes + seconds;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you think you need to return the raw material, totalSecs also, why don't you simply make it a member variable of Time class along with Hours, Minutes and Seconds and then return it like that:

```
public int getTotalSecs()
    { 
         return this.totalSecs;
    }
```